# Creating a Local Database in C# at Runtime (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, database

I am looking to create a database on the same computer as the program I am writing. The database needs to be created at runtime with all the basic information. I am able to add a database to the project via the Project>addItem menus but I would like to do it via the code. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Try looking into SQLite. The databases are a simple file, and you can setup the tables/schema in Visual Studio using the SQLite Toolbox add-in. The SQLite library is available as a Nuget package for your .NET project.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using ADO.NET easily. Although I suppose it can be achieved with Entity Framework too. This [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307283/how-to-create-a-sql-server-database-programmatically-by-using-ado.net-and-visual-c-.net) may help you

Hope this helps